How do nonclustered columnstore indexes in SQL Server handle linked updates and deletes with rowstore tables(either heap or clustered index tables)?
I have read several articles and blog posts describing that columnstore indexes store all fields redundantly, including the row IDs from the underlying rowstore table (either RID for heaps or clustered index keys for clustered tables).
Some articles mention that within a columnstore, each data row gets its own unique identifier internal to the columnstore index, and a delete bitmap or delete buffer uses this identifier (rowgroup ID and row number within the rowgroup) to mark specific rows as deleted.
However, these sources do not provide detailed explanations of how the columnstore index correlates an updated or deleted row in the rowstore table to the corresponding row in the columnstore index. If the process truly relies on the rowstore-based identifiers (like RID or clustered key), it seems impractical given that the columnstore index stores its own structure of data.
References Reviewed:

https://aboutsqlserver.com/2019/10/10/sql-server-2016-2017-critical-columnstore-index-bug-has-been-fixed/
https://aboutsqlserver.com/2017/11/28/splitting-and-merging-non-empty-partitions-in-columnstore-indexes/
https://sqlserverfast.com/epr/table-update/
https://aboutsqlserver.com/2013/10/15/sql-server-storage-engine-data-pages-and-data-rows/
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7759/sql-server-columnstore-indexes-tuple-mover-background-process/
https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2017-columnstore-in-place-updates/
http://www.nikoport.com/columnstore/

Could someone explain in detail the actual mechanism SQL Server uses to tie a row in the columnstore index to the corresponding row in the rowstore table for the purpose of correct and consistent updates and deletes, and how these operations are performed behind the scenes?
I’ve tried using the DBCC PAGE command to inspect the data pages, but the only concrete information I’ve found is that the delete bitmap stores a unique 9-byte identifier for each row.
I still don’t understand how these identifiers map back to the corresponding row in the original rowstore table or how the internal linking mechanism works for updates and deletes. Could someone provide a detailed explanation of this process?

Architecture
For secondary columnstore indexes, recently inserted or modified rows are stored in delta stores.
A delta store is a b-tree rowstore. It contains the same columns as the columnstore.
For primary (clustered) columnstore, this ID is simply a rowgroup sequence number and not stored in the compressed rowgroup. For secondary (nonclustered) columnstore, the ID is the heap RID or clustered b-tree locator (keys).
When a row is deleted from the base table, we know the RID/cluster locator, so it is quick and easy to find it if it is in a delta store. In that case, the (rowstore) delta store row is deleted and that's that.
The tricky part is if the row is not in a delta store. Scanning the whole columnstore for each deletion would obviously be highly inefficient.
Solution
The solution is to use an additional delete buffer.
Columnstore deletions are saved in this buffer and applied to the delete bitmap later by a background task. This task applies all the pending deletions using a single scan of the compressed rowgroups. We only know the unique base table row locator at this point, so that's what is stored in the buffer.
The delete bitmap is a bitmap in memory and a b-tree in persistent storage. In b-tree format, each entry is the logical row ID (sequence number, not stored) of the deleted row within the associated immutable rowgroup.
This batching idea for deletes is similar to the idea of batching inserts via delta stores with later compression into immutable rowgroups.
This means nonclustered columnstore scans now may also need to check the delete buffer as well as the delete bitmap. Clearly, one stops searching once a matching deletion indicator is found.
The delete buffer search is done with a batch mode hash antijoin that is normally hidden in execution plans. You can reveal it by enabling undocumented trace flag 8666.
Overview
Deletes are processed in the normal way for the base table and any rowstore dependencies (secondary indexes, constraints, indexed views etc.)
For any nonclustered columnstore index, SQL Server first checks any filtering condition on the index itself (filtered columnstore index). If the filter doesn't pass, there is nothing to do.
Otherwise, it looks in all the delta stores using the keys in the buffer. The assumption here is that most deletes and updates will target recently added rows, which are most likely to still be in a delta store.
If the row isn't found in a delta store, it is added to the delete buffer for later batched processing into the delete bitmap. Remember, this processing translates base table row locators into logical sequence numbers within a rowgroup.
Generations
The final issue is that compressed rowgroups might contain multiple old versions of a row with the same key.
To address this, each delete buffer entry is also marked with a generation number. This number is the same for every row in delta stores processed by the closure and compression process:
When a delta store is closed and converted to a compressed columnstore rowgroup, SQL Server increments the columnstore index's generation number. This number is assigned to the closed delta store and all rowgroups created by the conversion process.
Each delete buffer entry with generation number G and key K marks as deleted all rows with that key present in any rowgroup with a generation number <= G. You can see the generation number exposed in update and delete execution plans as a projection.
This logic is needed so SQL Server can hide only the correct deleted rows with otherwise matching keys.
Split updates
Updates are generally handled as a delete followed by an insert. From 2017 onward, an update may be performed in-place if the row is found in a delta store; otherwise, it is split.
Documentation: Real-Time Operational Analytics: DML operations and nonclustered columnstore index (NCCI) in SQL Server 2016

@Steven I have done my best to address your comments within the scope of the original question. I cannot speak to every piece of information you have found elsewhere on the internet, especially without a specific source link. It is natural to have follow-up questions about this complex topic, but they should be asked as separate (self-contained) single questions. The idea of a Q & A site is to provide focussed answers to one specific question at a time.
